# How to solve this jquery selector which in IE 8 doesn't work but IE 9 and firefox 8 work

Tags: jquery

The element is:

```
<input type="text" name="idName" id="idName" value="" size="2" maxlength="2" />
```

I use this selector:
`alert($('#idName').val());`

In IE 8:
cannot alert the content

In IE 9 and firefox 8:
can alert the content

why? How to fix?

Comment: You have trying to build it slowly? first only the type and id, is that working in all browsers add more attributes after?

Comment: Also, when is `alert()` called?

Comment: Also, make sure the code is well formed. Newer browsers can handle extraneous commas or missing semi-colons to some extent, where IE8 just fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the code that calls the `alert($('#idName').val());` is inside a `$(document).ready(function(){..});` part, so that it runs after the DOM is ready..

```
$(function(){
    alert($('#idName').val());
});
```